# Registering MySql data provider in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I need to create .NET application that uses databases. I want to use control data binding feature. I've added simple GridView to the form, and wanted to bind it to the MySql Table in database. But when I've choose SqlDataSource's connection, there wasn't MySql server. List consist of:

1. Access file
2. ODBC Data source
3. SQL Server
4. Oracle database
5. SQLite database file

MySql connector was installed. I wonder how to add to this list my custom data provider, in this case MySQL

Comment: Note: I do not know much about MySql-drivers. To integrate into visual studio a databaseprovider must implement the System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory interface and the provider should register itself in the machine.config. Maybe searching for your MySqlPRovider + DbProviderFactory + machineConfig helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've googled in your hint and have successfully registered provider, also I had manually maintained SqlDataSource. But I want to use a lot of data bindings, and manually maintain not very usefull for me, I want to maintain SqlDataSources by wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in MySQL Connector 6.0.7 After downloading newer Connector I was able to install adapter